# BLAKE3 for Block and Stream ciphers?

Tags: hash, block-cipher, stream-cipher, feistel-network, blake3

When assuming the following idea for ciphers:

For a block cipher, a 4-round balanced Feistel network where the PRF is BLAKE3 and the key schedule is: input key, input key with every odd bit flipped, input key with every even bit flipped, input key with every bit flipped.

For a stream cipher: a 64-bit unsigned int that gets concatenated with the key and hashed for each block of keystream, rounded to the nearest multiple that fits and the excess bytes trimmed off, then xor the keystream with the plaintext.

It just seems to me like these would be competitive with hardware-accelerated AES and ChaCha20, with the added benefit of being able to use quite large keys, in particular for a block cipher for disk encryption, where you could make a really large cipher and fit both the actual encryption key and block number into the key without the need for a tweak, and encrypt/decrypt more data in one go.

Beyond the risk of shoddy implementation is there any inherent risk in constructions like these? If we have a really good hash that's also fast, is there a point in even designing dedicated block and stream ciphers from the ground up?

Comment: Blake3 https://github.com/oconnor663/bao

Comment: Even in ideal case, using prfs, 4 rounds is not enough. Further, one has to account for imperfections in blake3. Finally, whatever primitive is built might require SPRP security, increasing the round count further. So I don’t see how to get away with less than 10 rounds. Also, the key schedule with bit flipping, makes the existing analysis invalid. It might still have some good properties but I wouldn’t « use » this construction.

Comment: Separate angle: why would you use BLAKE3, a hash function, for a block cipher that gets turned into stream cipher? Wouldn't it be simpler (and possibly faster) to just use ChaCha8 as a stream cipher?